# How to create upload button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, csv

I'm creating a Salesforce interface that lets user fill in a form and assign those values to objects' fields.

My form is mostly based on this tutorial: [LINK](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_forms)

I want to create an upload button, so that the users can upload CSV file with the fields, then the form will automatically get filled and new account are created.

Is there any good tutorial for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try this?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/example

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/example).

Here you already have code of working Upload button functionality where you control what type of file a User can upload!!